# UWP Accessing WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions class from C++?

Tags: c++, uwp, c++-winrt

I inherited a UWP application and I need to add additional functionality that needs to be implemented in C++.  Therefore, I'm building a C++ WinRT assembly that  will expose functionality that the existing UWP C# application will need to consume.

To that end, inside of that C++ WinRT project, I'm trying to make use of the `[WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions][1]` class in a C++ file. I cannot seem to find a header file on my system which declares the WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions class, and trying to reference it using the managed C++ keyword "using" as such:

```
#using <System.IO.dll>
```

..gives me the following compiler error:

```
"WinRT does not support #using of a managed assembly"
```

Comment: The WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions is a .NET method and it applies for UWP, why do you want to use WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions? You could try to create a c# component to use the class and then call it in c++/winrt.

Comment: As mentioned the application is a UWP application. Specifically, I need WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions because it has methods to convert between the two completely disparate Stream implementations between .NET and UWP. What I *wish* I could do is simply return a System.IO.Stream class from a WinRT C++ assembly, but I'm not even sure how to reference a System.IO.Stream object from a WinRT C++ assembly.

Comment: You cannot. Windows Runtime components can only expose Windows Runtime types. You cannot expose .NET types. The respective Windows Runtime stream types live in the [Windows.Storage.Streams Namespace](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.storage.streams). It is unclear, why you want to convert to .NET streams. You cannot use or even name those types in C++. What *problem* are you ultimately trying to solve here?

Comment: The application that needs to consume those Streams is written in C#, and already expects .NET Streams. Windows.Storage.Streams are a useless construct and an extremely questionable implementation decision by Microsoft. The assembly that I'm writing has to be in C++ in order to implement functionality that is missing in the UWP.

Comment: A Windows Runtime component's interface only allows you to expose Windows Runtime types. You cannot have anything other than Windows Runtime types pass the ABI. If your C# application needs to convert between WinRT stream types and .NET stream types, you can use the extension methods of [WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.windowsruntimestreamextensions?view=dotnet-plat-ext-3.0) in your C# code. That class is strictly .NET only, and cannot be used in C++ code.

Comment: .NET is not (well should not) be limited to C#. The original premise behind the CLR was that you could use any language. Excluding C++ from accessing functionality is a departure from that paradigm. Not to mention that I wouldn't have to use C++ if StreamSocket supported SNI in the first place.

Comment: You *can* use C++ with .NET. That requires use of language extensions ([C++/CLI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cpp/dotnet/dotnet-programming-with-cpp-cli-visual-cpp)). This will produce a mixed-mode assembly, containing both managed and unmanaged code. I don't know whether it is possible to turn a mixed-mode assembly into a Windows Runtime component. I also don't know whether C++/CLI and C++/WinRT can coexist. You should really consider asking about the problem you are trying to solve, rather than your solution.

Comment: "You can use C++ with .NET."  Except, for some classes, such as WindowsRuntimeStreamExtensions.

Comment: You can access .NET types using C++/CLI. You aren't using C++/CLI. You are using C++. C++ is not C++/CLI.